# How to track down process that's running too long?

Tags: linux, cpanel, vps, whm

I have a VPS with firewall and security notices enabled.  I keep getting emails like this:

```
Time:         Wed Jun 19 19:01:54 2019 -0500
Account:      user
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     7248 > 3600 (seconds)
Executable:   /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm
Command Line: php-fpm: pool domain_com                           
PID:          16374 (Parent PID:9915)
Killed:       No
```

So for some reason with this example I have a script that has apparently been running for 2+ hours non-stop.  I don't have anything that should be doing that.

I'm getting notices like this quite often.  How can I use this info to track down what specifically is causing this?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can track which the exact process with the process ID mentioned.

```
lsof -p 16374
```

The alert which you are getting is from the LDF which is installed as a part of CSF. I think its normal for cPanel with php_fpm to have the process php_fpm run this long.

You can add the php-fpm to csf.pignore file to stop this warning.
You can also refer the below cPanel fourm thread.
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/lfd-excessive-resource-usage-normal-for-php-fpm.592583/

Comment: I'm getting hundreds of them every day, though.  If it's normal, why would the LDF service be set to send notices about such a thing?  I'll review the link you sent, thanks.  If I do add php-fpm to csf.pignore, I assume that only stops these warnings, but still allows the other warnings that LDF sends to come through?  I just want to see the stuff that I actually need to see.

Comment: ***> why would the LDF service be set to send notices about such a thing?***

It is sending those alerts since you have installed CSF/LFD and left the settings as default. LFD is configured to send alerts if the process time exceeds 3600 seconds. You can see this from below alert.

`Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     7248 > 3600 (seconds)`

If you add php-fpm to csf.pignore, it will only stop warnings related to php-fpm. You continue to receive other warnings as usual. If you look at csf.pignore it will contain other service names.

Answer (score 1):

To get more information on processes, I would use the Htop tool. [This is a great article for learning about how to manage processes using htop and ps](https://www.howtogeek.com/107217/how-to-manage-processes-from-the-linux-terminal-10-commands-you-need-to-know/)

Lsof (List open files) will tell you more information about what files the process is using.

You can get htop and lsof with

```
sudo apt install htop lsof -y
```

[This article indicates that](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/php-fpm-consuming-more-resources.624355/) :
That message comes from the third-party CSF/LFD application and indicates a PHP-FPM process was running longer than the maximum time configured for the CSF/LFD detection period. It shows the process was not killed, thus you should not have traffic loss.

So you might want to check the PHP-FPM error log for the account in-question to see if you notice any particular error messages. It's located at:

```
/home/$username/logs/domain_tld.php.error.log
```

It looks like your specific issue has not been resolved on that form. So, you might want to try strace. It handles watching system calls made by a given process including all read-write operations and os function calls. You can activate it on the command line before the program you want to track or attach to a running process by hitting s on a process selected in htop.